# Alter a existing SQL statement, to give an additional column of data, but to not affect performance, so best approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In this query, I want to add a new column, which gives the SUM of a.VolumetricCharge, but only where PremiseProviderBillings.BillingCategory = 'Water'. But i don't want to add it in the obvious place since that would limit the rows returned, I only want it to get the new column value

```
 SELECT b.customerbillid,
         -- Here i need  SUM(a.VolumetricCharge) but where a.BillingCategory is equal to 'Water'
         Sum(a.volumetriccharge)                AS Volumetric,
         Sum(a.fixedcharge)                     AS Fixed,
         Sum(a.vat)                             AS VAT,
         Sum(a.discount) + Sum(deferral)        AS Discount,
         Sum(Isnull(a.estimatedconsumption, 0)) AS Consumption,
         Count_big(*)                           AS Records
  FROM   dbo.premiseproviderbillings AS a WITH (nolock)
         LEFT JOIN dbo.premiseproviderbills AS b WITH (nolock)
                ON a.premiseproviderbillid = b.premiseproviderbillid
  -- Cannot add a where here since that would limit the results and change the output
  GROUP  BY b.customerbillid;
```

Comment: use `CASE` expression. `SUM(CASE WHEN  PremiseProviderBillings.BillingCategory = 'Water' THEN a.VolumetricCharge END)`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using meaningless table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a tricky one, as what you're asking for will definitely affect performance (your asking SQL Server to do more work after all!).

However, we can add a column to your results which performs a *conditional* sum so that it does not affect the result of the other columns.

The answer lies in using a `CASE` expression!

```sql
Sum(
  CASE
    WHEN PremiseProviderBillings.BillingCategory = 'Water' THEN
      a.volumetriccharge
    ELSE
      0
  END
) AS WaterVolumetric
```